# Javascript function is undefined in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am trying to execute a simple function to execute what a users email is. If I delete everything in the javascript file besides the function itself everything works just fine, can anyone spot an issue with this code that would cause this to break? How should I initialize firebase in one javascript file so that I can reuse the initialization across multiple files?

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/getUsersNameR.js"></script>
</head>

<span>Welcome, <strong><script>usersEmail()</script></strong></span><br>
```

JS:

```
  var firebase = require("firebase");
var $;
$ = require('jquery');
```

require("firebase/firestore");

```
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


  // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
var db = firebase.firestore();

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var email;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
  email = user.email;
  alert("TEST");
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}


function userEmail() {
    document.write("TEST");
}
```

Comment: you cant do functions directly in html like that

Comment: There's not enough detail in this question to figure out what the problem may be. See [this article on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the path of your js reference is wrong. Double check the path. Otherwise the code looks good

DEMO

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function usersEmail() {
              document.write("TEST");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            usersEmail();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a way to test if a script include was successful?

Comment: goto developer tools in chrome and check network path if your script is loaded

Comment: The script is loaded, but still says that the usersEmail is undefined

Comment: make sure you load the script before you invoke the method

Comment: How do I make sure that the script loads first? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

don't call the function through a script tag, if you want to call a function when the page loads use the body tag's onload attribute.   example:

```
<body onload="myFunction();"><div id="myText">other code</div></body>
```

and have the myFunction() function set the text value of a certain id to whatever you want. Example:

```
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = "My  text";
}
```